# use google.cloud python library insidr Github Actions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I need to use the google cloud sdk on pthyon.
The code works well on my local environment.

```py
from google.cloud import translate

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": projectId,
            "contents": [text],
            "mime_type": mime_type,
            "source_language_code": "en-US",
            "target_language_code": "es",
        }
    )
```

But I'm not sure how integrate it inside a github action.

```yaml
jobs:
  update-dep:
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v2"
        name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
        with:
          project_id: "project-12345"
          workload_identity_provider: "projects/12345/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github/providers/project"
      - name: PythonScript
        run: |
          python ./script.py
```

Looks like `google-github-actions/auth@v2` is working fine, the output is:

`Created credentials file at "/home/runner/foo/bar/gha-creds-b8701ebd3eb851cb.json"`

But I don't know if I need to do something with that json file or if I need to add additional code in my python script.

The output from translate_text call is:

```
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.Unknown: None Authentication backend unknown error.
```

Any hint?

Comment: Which library you use to get credentials?
How does your python script know where to look for credential?
 Maybe locally you have it in some 'common' directory, e.g. `~/. config/gcloud` and its different than your `/foo/bar/ `

Comment: Try specifying your local credentials with `from_service_account_json` maybe?

Comment: Credentials are generated by "google-github-actions/auth@v2", based on the documentation It's populate GOOGLE_GHA_CREDS_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.

The error not was on the python code or the github action.

Looks like something is wrong with my google account configuration.

The service_account is fine but something is wrong with my workload_identity_provider configuration.

Setting service_account on the github action fix my issue.

```
  - uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v2"
    name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
    with:
      project_id: "project-12345"
      workload_identity_provider: "projects/12345/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github/providers/project"
      service_account: test@project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```